# Program that can visit a webpage at a set duration

Tags: windows, web

Looking for a program that will simply visit a webpage every 6 minutes. Preferably without opening a new tab (I tried using Task Scheduler, but it would open a new tab every time)

Comment: Do you want this done in a browser window, or are you just confirming the site is alive?

Comment: Just confirming the site. Actually, I think any sort of command line program would probably be best, so I can just run it on my vps

Answer (score 2):

To simply connect and check if a page returns, you can use either `curl` or `wget` on a command line or from a `cron` scheduled task.

You'll of course want to wrap it in a shell script to either send an alert or cause other behavior on fail/pass

Answer (score 1):

WebChangeMonitor will do exactly what you want.

You can set the interval at which the page will be checked, and it can even display the differences in the HTML.  It is fast, efficient, and works very well.

You can configure it to check almost any number of pages (upper limit unknown).

Furthermore, you can set the User Agent being used for the HTTP/HTTPS requests.

It is gratis and open-source.  The source code and executables are available here:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/webchangemon/